# How to fetch complete webpage (using javascript) in python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm trying to use urllib2 to fetch webpage from a website. After I managed to log on and retrieve the page, I found out the page has some `<script>.....</script>` inside. How can I save the rendered the output (the complete content of the webpage, not the script)?

Comment: Are you saying you'd like to save the content of the page, after any included Javascript has been run?

Comment: Are you doing this for testing, screen-scraping for an application, or what?  In general, with JavaScript it's the browser that creates the page content, so you need a real browser to duplicate that...

Comment: @MattLuongo Yes, I'm trying to pull some of my personal message from a website which doesn't offer an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also like to mention [pywebkitgtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/) (which I've been using a lot lately as an embedded browser), and [Selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: Selenium with an actual browser driver is very useful, can mimic most human interactions.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript can't be easily handled if you are using urllib.

What you need is a headless browser, for ex. WebKit.

A simple example can be found [here.](http://sitescraper.net/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/)

If you don't want yourself to be limited to python, try [Phantomjs](http://www.phantomjs.org/)